# Where are the Jira Application properties stored

Tags: automation, jira, atlassian-crowd

I am installing [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to avoid the web browser installation process. I am trying to automate the below part of the wizard:

[image]

So I wonder were are these properties stored:

1. Are those stored on Database tables (which tables are those) ?
2. Are those values stored on key=value properties files under **jira_install_directory**?
3. Is this stored in other place?

I am trying to automate those properties and configuration using Ansible and avoid the web browser process.